# Programmatically access the "Open with" Windows Explorer menu list from .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows-shell, windows-explorer

When right-clicking a file in Windows Explorer, the "Open with" menu item displays a list of available applications, based on the file type of the clicked file.

See this picture as an example:

[image: "Open with" context menu in Windows Explorer]
<sub>(source: [magerquark.de](http://magerquark.de/data/misc/open-with.png))</sub>

Now I want to be able to programmatically read the list of applications for a given file extension/type (e.g. "png") from within a C# .NET 2.0 application.

E.g.

```
public class FileOpenInfo
{
    public string ApplicationName { get; }
    public string ApplicationPath { get; }

    public static FileOpenInfo[] GetInformation( string extension );
}
```

**Question:**

Is it possible to get this list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list of programs associated with a file extension are stored in the Windows Registry.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts
```

The Microsoft.Win32 [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32?view=net-6.0) contains the classes to access the registry.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look. I guess that the application probably needs administrative permissions (which it doesn't have) to enumerate the registry.

Comment: My guess is that enumerating will be possible without elevation. Make sure you use the proper overload of the RegistryKey class to open it read-only.